# Importing Teradata Code to PowerBI, PowerBI can't accept double quotes

Tags: powerbi, teradata, powerbi-datasource

**Decided to change the column name in the source table, I do not believe that there is a solution to the issue besides configuring our Teradata connector to work with LDAP or changing the name of the source column.  Since we're still investigating the Teradata connector, this was the faster solution.**

I'm attempting to import a table created by a Teradata query into PowerBI as a dataflow using the blank query entity.

The original code is something like this:

```
Select ft."Actual Name of the Column"

from fake.fake_table ft
```

PowerBI is getting hung up on the double quotes, but I can't figure out a way around them since they're required to call the column in Teradata.  Short of changing the column name in the source table, is there a way to call this column without double quotes?

PS: Using the Teradata connection inside PowerBI is not an option for our organization due to the lack of LDAP support.

Comment: If double quotes are part of the string, you can try wrapping them in single quotes: '"xxx"'.

Comment: The Teradata connector *does* have LDAP support, though it's hidden by default. You need to set the value of environment variable `PBI_EnableTeradataLdap` to True for the checkbox to appear.

Comment: The double quotes aren't part of the string, they're used to qualify the object name.  I've passed along the info about LDAP support to our Power BI admin, if we could use the Teradata connector that would be the ideal scenario.

Comment: As far as your original question, have you tried escaping / doubling the double quotes, i.e. `ft.""Actual Name of the Column""`?

Comment: Yes, it appears that when using the blank query in Power BI, any double quote, aside from the ones required for the black query syntax, will cause an error.  We went ahead and changed the column name from the source, I don't think there is a workaround for this that can be solved by code.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to replace the "" with [].

Otherwise, change the architecture such that PBI reads from a View instead of a table and rename fields as you need.

Comment: `[]`isn't valid for Teradata. To qualify object names, you have to use double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution could be:

```
create macro mc_select_data
AS
(
   Select ft."Actual Name of the Column"
   from fake.fake_table ft;
);
exec mc_select_data;
```